# I cannot delete a record "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails. How set ON DELETE SET NULL option for FOREIGN KEY?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I tried to delete a record in ratings table,then

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (fyprojectdb.ratings, CONSTRAINT FKdyash6f91887unaan9mj9b460 FOREIGN KEY (answer_id) REFERENCES answers (answer_id))

In this case I am trying to delete parent row while child row(s) exists. I think I have to set ON DELETE SET NULL option for this FOREIGN KEY. How do I do that for this case?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ratings")
public class Ratings {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long rating_id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 45)
    private Short ratingValue;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id")
    private Answer answer;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;
//getters and setters
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answers")
public class Answer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long answer_id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 100)
    private String fullAnswer;

    /*Many to one mapping question*/
    @ManyToOne(cascade = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;

    /* Many to One mapping with users*/
    @ManyToOne(cascade = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;
//getters and setters
```

Comment: In the code, how are you deleting the `Ratings` entity?

Comment: @DavideD'Alto I am using axios post and call this deleteQuestion endpoint``` @PostMapping("/deleteQuestion")
    public String deleteQuestion(@RequestParam Long questionId){

        questionRepository.deleteById(questionId);


        return "redirect:/forum.html";
    }```

Comment: If you are deleting a record in the 'Ratings' table, why is a foreign key constraint it has TO the answers table a problem? You should be able to delete rows from Ratings without nulling out any of its foreign keys. Your constraint violation error is telling you something else is going on, such as you are modifying the Ratings row before deleting it; turn on SQL logging and see the statements generated, and then look over your code to see what you are doing in your transactional/EntityManager context to cause it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you fetch the children before:

```
questionRepository.deleteById(questionId);
```

and set their foreign key to null.
Somthing like:

```
@PostMapping("/deleteQuestion") 
public String deleteQuestion(@RequestParam Long questionId){ 
//fetch your children here and set all foreign keys to null
questionRepository.deleteById(questionId); 
return "redirect:/forum.html"; }
```

Comment: what do you mean by fetch your children here and set all foreign keys to null ?

Comment: @IUKottahchchi, the user wants to keep all the children without any parent. Hence, fetching the children and setting their foreign key to null might be the solution in my view.
Do you see anything wrong with the approach?